# Sharepoint documents outside of Sharepoint

Tags: wiki

I am evaluating Wiki software. I want to provide a knowledge base to a broad range of people, both those who have access to Sharepoint (through login/authentication), and those who do not (workers on the production floor). Can I make those documents, which are in Sharepoint, available to individuals who do NOT have access to Sharepoint?

Comment: outside mean out of company via internet or outside mean with in company with no access to sharepoint?

Comment: you would need a web application that has anonymous access enabled so the production floor employees can hit it